# C# Xaml WebBrowser.DocumentText Youtube Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having a problem with `WebBrowser.DocumentText`

I receive this error :

> WebBrowser does not contain a definition for 'DocumentText' and no
> accessible extension method 'DocumentText' accepting a first argument
> of type 'WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?

Code :

```
string _yUrl;
public string VideoID
{
    get
    {
        var yMatch = new Regex(@"http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=]*)?").Match(_yUrl);
        return yMatch.Success ? yMatch.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
   
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _yUrl = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ1Z0zZHktI;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = String.Format("<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'/><iframe width='100%' height='315'" +
        " src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}?autoplay=0' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer;" +
        " encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>", VideoID);
}
```

Comment: `DocumentText` isn't a property on the WPF's WebBrowser control (though it is on the WinForm's WebBrowser control). You could try the method [NavigateToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring?view=net-5.0).

Comment: quaabam nope its not working its saying : No overload for method 'NavigateToString' takes 2 arguments